# Map list to dictionary by template

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I got list with some data like

```
l = ['1', '01.01.2000', 'code1', '2', '01.02.2000', 'code2', etc... ]
```

I need to convert this list to list of dicts, grouping items by 3. Adding values **id, date, code** as keys for dict

```
l = [{'id': '1', 'date':'01.01.2000', 'code':'code1'},
     {'id': '1', 'date':'01.01.2000', 'code':'code1'},
     etc...]
```

i use this function to split list in tuples by 3 elements

```
def group(lst, n):
  for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
    val = lst[i:i+n]
    if len(val) == n:
      yield tuple(val)
```

but don't know how to convert each tuple to dict with keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your code slightly to use list unpacking:

```
def group(lst, n):
  dict_list = []    
  for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
    val = lst[i:i+n]
    dic = {}
    dic['id'], dic['date'], dic['code'] = val
    dict_list.append(dic)
  return dict_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Short solution:

```
l = ['1', '01.01.2000', 'code1', '2', '01.02.2000', 'code2']
result = [{'id':l[i], 'date':l[i+1], 'code':l[i+2]} for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[{'date': '01.01.2000', 'id': '1', 'code': 'code1'}, {'date': '01.02.2000', 'id': '2', 'code': 'code2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a different approach using list comprehensions:

```
keys = ["id", "date", "code"]
[dict(zip(keys, l[i:i+3])) for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
```